# Pre-Hijacking Mitigation

Tags: attack-prevention, password-reset, single-sign-on

I want to create a website with password login and social login (e.g. Google only.)

For password login, first I will send a verification email.

I want to prevent pre-hijacking.
For those who do not know pre-hijacking: https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2022/05/23/pre-hijacking-attacks/

- Attacker creates an account e.g. victim@gmail.com and with a password e.g. "Att@cker123"
- System sends an email to victim@gmail.com
- Victim clicks the verification link by accident.
- Or later he tries to sign up my website. The site warns that an account already exists but not verified. The site presents a "send the verification email again" link. The victim clicks the link and also the new link at the email.
- Then the attacker will be able login with password "Att@cker123".

Same vulnerability occurs when password login and social login are both used. (Classic-Federated Merge Attack)

I have found below mitigation. Is it correct, is it a known best practice, or are there any better solutions?

- I will not be asking password for user sign-up.
- I will send a verification link.
- Verification link asks for password and confirm password. Then I set verified status and the password_hash given.

Again, is it correct, is it a known best practice, or are there any better solutions?
I think this prevents also Classic-Federated Merge Attack.